# Connectting intercom audio into sound card

Tags: protection, sound-card

I want to connect the intercom in my apartment to a sound card, both input and output. The voltage of the intercom mic and speaker signals (2 different cables) is 12V while not load is applied. When the speaker or the mic of the intercom are connected, the voltage drops to around 4.5V. In the attached image you can see the signal on the mic wire when a 2kHz sine sound wave is played near the mic. As you can see, the signal saturates at around 4.6 peak-to-peak voltage.

[image: 1]

So, i need a protective circuit to connect the speaker signal from my intercom to the mic input of my sound card and the mic signal from my intercom to the speaker signal of my sound card.
For the sound card input protection, I was thinking in using a decoupling capacitor in series, a 6:1 voltage divider and two diodes in parallel for over voltage protection. Is this enough? What about the grounds, do I need to use an isolation transformer?.

**Edit: Added intercom schematic**

[image]

The intercom is a wall-mounted phone.
The six wires in the top left go inside the wall.
J1 and J2 are connected with a 4-wires patch cord, just like a normal telephone.
L1 is the buzzer.

Comment: Is there any chance at all that you can find a schematic for your intercom? The sound card is relatively "standard" and most of us can "suss" that out on our own, or already have ideas there. The problem (and it's wonderful you took the time to develop a picture) is that the intercom system is self-contained and designed for a specific purpose which doesn't include such connections. I'd like to know more about how to interpret what you presented. A schematic would go a very long way in helping.

Comment: There you have it :). To clarify, what i'm trying to do is give my intercom VoIP functionality with a Raspberry Pi. So I need to connect the intercom to the audio input and output of the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: One of the perhaps tricky things to figure out here is the ground reference, which may not be what you suspect *at all*!  You might consider acoustic coupling or an isolation transformer, in either case with a relay for the push-to-talk button.